# xcf2png -- XCF version 12 not supported

Tags: gimp, png

- Gimp 2.10.8
- Ubuntu 19.10
- xcftools_1.0.7-6_amd64

I want to use commandline to convert Gimp xcf files to png.The output file `rose.png` is a fail.

```
xcf2png rose.xcf -o rose.png 
Warning: XCF version 12 not supported (trying anyway...)
```

Comment: The failure should be a bug report. Failure on "Warning" instead of "Error" might be a second bug report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xcf2png` is too old and does not support XCF 11, 12 versions. But if you want to convert xcf files using terminal, run the next script-command in the folder with .xcf files:

```
gimp -n -i -b - <<EOF
(let* ( (file's (cadr (file-glob "*.xcf" 1))) (filename "") (image 0) (layer 0) )
  (while (pair? file's) 
    (set! image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE (car file's) (car file's))))
    (set! layer (car (gimp-image-merge-visible-layers image CLIP-TO-IMAGE)))
    (set! filename (string-append (substring (car file's) 0 (- (string-length (car file's)) 4)) ".png"))
    (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image layer filename filename)
    (gimp-image-delete image)
    (set! file's (cdr file's))
    )
  (gimp-quit 0)
  )
EOF
```

As a result, png file appears with correct image:

```
$ ls
red_rectangle.png  red_rectangle.xcf
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5846727/10854998)

Comment: I get this as output `Welcome to TinyScheme, Version 1.40
Copyright (c) Dimitrios Souflis` and the images are converted!

Comment: @StephenBoston yes, because of it uses current gimp installation. At the same time, xcf2png is independent tool which is requires maintenance efforts in case of newer gimp releases come out.

Comment: I upvoted, because it is simple and effective

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find anything more recent than [this](https://github.com/j-jorge/xcftools) and it seems to have never been updated since Gimp 2.8.

Gimp 2.10 uses a new version of XCF to support

- high-bit-depth layers
- additional layer blend modes
- compression

If none of these are used you can have Gimp 2.10 save files in 2.8-compatible format (there are indications at the bottom of the file save dialog).

Otherwise you will have to use a Gimp script to do the conversion.